# How to setup a router-link?

Tags: angular

I have read several blog posts[1](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/16/routing-in-angular-2.html), including the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouterLink-class.html), that `router-link` can be setup using the following markup:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a router-link="start">Start</a></li>
    <li><a router-link="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a router-link="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and RouteConfig:

```js
import { Start } from './components/start';
import { About } from './components/about';
import { Contact } from './components/contact';

// ...

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Start, as 'start'}
  { path: '/about', component: About, as 'about'}
  { path: '/contact', component: Contact, as 'contact'}
])
```

Running the above code using 2.0.0-alpha.31 build produces the following error:

```
TypeError: list.reduce is not a function in [red in null]
STACKTRACE:
Error: TypeError: list.reduce is not a function in [red in null]
    at ChangeDetectionError.BaseException (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:9569:24)
    at new ChangeDetectionError (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:13676:17)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.throwError (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:14477:16)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_App_comp_0.detectChangesInRecords (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:16974:17), <anonymous>:30:16)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:14443:15)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInShadowDomChildren (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:14464:19)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:14447:15)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:14438:74)
    at LifeCycle.tick (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:34739:35)
    at tick (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app.js:30323:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `angular2/router@0.5.3` | `2.0.0-alpha.38` this appears to have changed.

The link points to the alias of the route and aliases have to be CamelCase (technically PascalCase).

```js
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/Start']">Start</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/About']">About</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/Contact']"Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Start, name: 'Start'}
  { path: '/about', component: About, name: 'About'}
  { path: '/contact', component: Contact, name: 'Contact'}
])
```

Looks like they're trying to ensure users don't confuse the binding with the route path.

*Sources:*

- [angular/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha38-2015-10-03)
- [angular/issues#4083](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4083)
- [angular/commit/5298eb0](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5298eb0)

**Update:**

As of `2.0.0-alpha.45`

- the `RouteConfig` property `as` was changed to `name`

Source:

- [angular/commit/7d83959](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/7d83959be56780b1ba9cf7efb6cd96452bec2761)

Answer (score 3):

The markup to define a `router-link` is:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/start']">Start</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/about']">About</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['/contact']"Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Refer to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2845#issuecomment-122089915.

Comment: Here is an example of a working router using the link format above: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0